# Crystal report - export to pdf with unknown language

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports

who can help me why i got the report as picture when i view report or export to PDF, i don't know why the report has dots and question mark under words. It should be English. I run on server and client also got this problem. If I export to MS Words or another format then this problem disappear.[image]

Please help me to advise why this problem appear.

Answer (score 0):

According to me,crystal reports supports only True Type fonts.
Check link to understand the difference between both the fonts
([description](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080621145425AAuKtgk)).
The font you are using may be a Open type font, that CR doesnt support. Just for testing try using a True type font and see if PDF prints, if it doesnt then the problem may not be fonts, and may be somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but let tell me what is the True type? i don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

PDF export uses your default PC language. So, set your machine language and everything should be printed in that language.

Comment: Our report should use both English and Vietnamese, PC languague always is English.

Comment: How do you set Vietnamese? I was making reports at English PC and when a collegue tried to export them at Swedish PC, he got time stamps and page number in swedish. So... Go to Control Panel -> Regional Settings and set everything in one language. This problem occurs only in PDF. Give me a feedback if not a problem. @BahienNguyen

Comment: Yes, everything in one language as your comment. I set Calibri for Vietnamese, Arial for English. And now, the English is good, but Vietnamese got some dots and question marks under words, this problem just happen in PDF only, another type files are so good. I don't know how to solve this case. I installed Unicode MS fonts before.